# Panels selection rule node author

Tags: panels

I was wondering, I have a panels using the "Node template", is there a way to have "node author" as a selection rule, now I only have "node type".

I'm using Drupal 7.9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under the "Contexts" tab for your page variant, add a relationship to Node:author.  This will expose the available fields from the author for your use.

However, What are you trying to do?  You might be better off to define what you want in Views and then set up a node page variant to display the view for you.

Answer (score 0):

Just an fyi, in case you are attempting to override the node edit form using panels, and selection rules, you may have to use the dev version of ctools. I was banging my head against the wall for a while trying to figure out why certain selection rules where not displaying. Once i replaced ctools with the dev version, everything worked fine